# parallel processing for apply function

Tags: python, parallel-processing, joblib

I have a dataframe of 100,000 records so i tried to do a Parallel processing using the joblib library which works fine with my code below, but my question is can i try the same code with 'apply' and 'lambda' function which seems like very close to my original code with minimum change instead of using the for loop like in my code. Please help

Original Code -  Without parallel processing:

```
df['b1'] = df.text1.apply(lambda x: removeNumbers(x))
```

With parallel processing:

For the purpose of applying the Joblib's parallel processing i converted to for loop below

```
df['b1'] = Parallel(n_jobs = -1)(delayed(removeNumbers)(x) for x in df.text1)
```

Comment: just use pandarallel library as it is way better than joblib and you would only need to do: df.text1.parallel_apply(lambda x: removeNumbers(x)

Comment: actually, you could do: df["text1"].parallel_apply(removeNumbers)

Comment: sure will try this, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have the following code which I use when I have a large dataframe and want to use parallel computing:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
from multiprocessing import  Pool, cpu_count
from functools import partial

# Wrapper to time functions (not needed for parallel computing but to show that it works...)
def time_function(func):
    def decorated_func(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.perf_counter_ns()
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        stop = time.perf_counter_ns()
        temp = []
        temp += [type(a) for a in args]
        f = lambda x: f"{x}={type(kwargs[x])}"
        temp += list(map(f, kwargs))
        print(f"Function {func.__name__}{*temp,}: time elapsed: {(stop - start)*1e-6:.3f} [ms]")
        return  ret
    return decorated_func

# This function splits the data and calls the functions.
def parallelize(data, func, num_of_processes=cpu_count()):
    data_split = np.array_split(data, num_of_processes)
    p = pool(num_of_processes)
    data = pd.concat(p.map(func, data_split))
    p.close()
    p.join()
    return data

# This function is only used for pandas (otherwise the parallelize function was enough)
def run_on_subset(func, data_subset):
    return data_subset.apply(func, axis=1)

# This function is maybe redundant, but it keeps the code readable.
def parallelize_on_rows(data, func, num_of_processes=8):
    return parallelize(data, partial(run_on_subset, func), num_of_processes)

def sum_two_columns(row):
    time.sleep(0.1) # Make it a time consuming function
    return row[0] + row[1]

@time_function
def oridnary_apply(df):
    return df.apply(sum_two_columns, axis=1)

@time_function
def parallel_apply(df):
    return parallelize_on_rows(df, sum_two_columns)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    array = np.ones((100, 3))
    df = pd.DataFrame(array)
    print(f"cpu_count: {cpu_count()}")
    oridnary_apply(df)
    parallel_apply(df)
    print('done')

>>> cpu_count: 12
>>> Function oridnary_apply(<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>,): time elapsed: 10860.275 [ms]
>>> Function parallel_apply(<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>,): time elapsed: 2170.105 [ms]
>>> done
```

EDIT:

When a lot of values in your rows are equal then it is also possible to cache the your function. If it is a complex function, that means the execution time is relative long, this is also a way to speed up the apply function for your DataFrame.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache